# Fitnesse - Map exception to failure

Tags: fitnesse

**Situation**: Our clients are designed to just run through (void) if everything is ok and throw dedicated exceptions, if a bad situation occurrs (e.g. registering a user with a username that already exists).

We're using [Slim Decision Tables](http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.FullReferenceGuide.UserGuide.WritingAcceptanceTests.SliM.DecisionTable). An example fixture would look like this:

```
public class MyFixture {

    private final Client client;
    private String someKey;
    private String accessToken;

    public MyFixture() {
        client = initClient();
    }

    public void setSomeKey(final String someKey) {
        this.someKey = someKey;
    }

    public void setAccessToken(final String accessToken) {
        this.accessToken = accessToken;
    }

    public final void execute() {
        // this execution may throw an Exception that inherits from RuntimeException 
        // and contains a String field called errorCode which can validate against
        client.executeFailableRequest(someKey, accessToken);
    }
}
```

**Question**: Fitnesse displays exceptions yellow, but I'd like to see them as red failures. Is that possible?

We know that catching the exception and evaluating its content is possible, but would prefer a less bulky way.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how exactly your clients are connected to FitNesse? I mean stuff like: are you using Fit or Slim as test system, what kind of table are you using, what do your fixtures look like?

Comment: Added more details.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can make a row red in a decision table's `execute()` method. But you could catch the exception there and evaluate in your table explicitly whether an error is thrown. Something like:

```
public class MyFixture {

    private final Client client;
    private String someKey;
    private String accessToken;
    private String lastError;

    public MyFixture() {
        client = new Client();
    }

    public void setSomeKey(final String someKey) {
        this.someKey = someKey;
    }

    public void setAccessToken(final String accessToken) {
        this.accessToken = accessToken;
    }

    public final void execute() {
        try {
            // this execution may throw an Exception that inherits from RuntimeException
            // and contains a String field called errorCode which can validate against
            client.executeFailableRequest(someKey, accessToken);
            lastError = null;
        } catch (MyError e) {
            lastError = e.getErrorCode();
        }
    }

    public String errorCode() {
        return lastError;
    }
}
```

and table

```
|my fixture                      |
|some key|access token|errorCode?|
|key     |a           |null      |
|a       |b           |null      |
```

If the error/exception can be thrown by many methods (i.e. you can't just add a try/catch to the `execute` method but would have to do so in many methods) you can make your fixture implement `InteractionAwareFixture`. This allows you to 'intercept' all calls from Slim to your fixture and add custom handling (like an aspect applied to all calls).

You could also look at rewriting your fixture to be a ['table table'](http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.WritingAcceptanceTests.SliM.TableTable) which gives more/full control over how your table is evaluated. Then you choose which colours to give to which cells.

And a final approach is to implement your own Slim table, instead of using the decision table, but this can be quite complicated in my experience, and seems a bit over the top for the problem at hand.